# Organizing Redmine projects

Tags: redmine, organization

I am setting up Redmine for our company. Thing is that every department has their hands in every project. And sometimes one project/issue may affect another project. Our projects vary, but usually our deliveries are once a year (major versions can be 1-2 years long).

I have been trying to find some resources of how other companies have implemented redmine to work across their company. Does anyone have some links that I could use to better plan/organize my redmine?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow as it is either way too broad, too subjective or it just asks for remote tutorials or resources. Each of these issues alone makes a question unsuitable here as they can not authoritatively be answered in a way that both helps you and future visitors of this question. You might find more help at the Redmine forums or by consulting general project management literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also read :

http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/47595

and see that today, nobody answer ...

My answer is that:
 - it's very rare that people explain who they used redmine
 - it's quite complicate, and so many depend of your companie

So I recommand : try, experiment, and accept to change.

My experience :
  - first period : one projet, somes sub-projects
  - second period : one project and eavy used of task and sub task
  - third period : somes projects, more sub projects, and still eavy use of task and sub-task.

Best regard